# Externally loaded images in AS3 un-clickable?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flashdevelop

I'm loading in an external image (a book cover from goodreads.com) into a library viewer AIR app (used on ipad and in-browser) running on Starling (in case you need to know). After it loads, the cover should be clickable to take further action.

This all works fine on ipad and when directly built from FlashDevelop, but when it's viewed in-browser, click events don't do anything on the loaded images. It'll work on my embedded placeholder bitmaps no problem (sitting in a "Book" class extending Sprite).

It seems to be a security problem, but if it was, I'd expect the image to not load at all. But instead it loads but isn't interactive anymore. I've tried various things like:

- Add loader and click listener to the Book object
- Add loader.content as Bitmap and click listener to the Book
- Create a BitmapData and draw the Loader.content, then add the resulting Bitmap (it's blank in-browser, but works perfectly when built from FD)
- Add loader and place a transparent sprite on top of it, add listener to the sprite

Has anyone had this problem? Would anyone know a work-around?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reference to `Loader.content` should throw an error given the crossdomain.xml on goodreads.com. You are probably trying to add the click handler after an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a sand-box problem.

I think it's intentional; you shouldn't be able to hot-link other site's assets unless given express permission.

I fixed this by only pulling images hosted locally and using `crossdomain.xml` to make sure there was no lookup issues when `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` were different.